# Why do my material select values get removed when I make a selection?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to use Angular Material form controls. I have a mat-select. When I choose an option, the values get removed, but the choices still display. For example, I am dumping the form values to the screen to observe the behavior. When I select an option, the dumped values on the screen disappear, but the choices still display in the drop-down. What is odd is that is works if I replace mat-select with the native select. Any thoughts as to what I am doing incorrectly?

I replaced mat-select with native select. It works with that, but does not have all of the material design I would like. I have not been able to get it to work per the docs with mat-select.

```
// This does not work and clears out when an option is selected
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Pay Category</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="payCategory">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let payCategory of payCategories"
                    [ngValue]="payCategory">
          {{payCategory.description}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
// This works, but removes some of the material design styling
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Pay Category</mat-label>
    <select matNativeControl
            formControlName="payCategory">
        <option *ngFor="let payCategory of payCategories"
                [ngValue]="payCategory">
          {{payCategory.description}}
        </option>
    </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
// In case you wish to see the component relevant code, this is the FormControl...
payCategory: new FormControl( this.buildPayCategories() )
```

```
// Pull in payCategories for select list from service
  buildPayCategories () {
    this.payCategories = this.timeEntry.payCategories;
    return this.payCategories;
  }
```

I would rather use the mat-select to take advantage of material design styling rather than having it simply clear out the value selected.

```
// buildPayCategories returns an array of objects. Here is a sample...
0: {payCategoryId: 1, description: "Converted Data ", payType: "Salary", isActive: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem but for me it works.

Except instead of `[ngValue]` I use `[value]`. You can find [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aeeyokplndq) on Stackblitz a working example hope it helps.

**Edit**
Based on your update:

```
  public options = [
    {payCategoryId: 1, description: "Converted Data ", payType: "Salary", isActive: true},
    {payCategoryId: 1, description: "Something Else ", payType: "Salary", isActive: true}
  ];
  public selected = this.options[0];
  public payCategory =  new FormControl(this.options)
```

and the template:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Pay Category</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="payCategory" [(value)]="selected">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let payCategory of options"
                    [value]="payCategory">
          {{payCategory.description}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>You selected: {{selected.description}}</p>
```

This is working just fine, have a look!

Good luck!

Comment: It worked when I plugged in hard-coded options like in your example, but not with my mat-options that is pulling from the component, which puls it from a service. Thoughts on that process?

Comment: Can you update the answer with the values returned by your method `buildPayCategories` please?